# how to properly share data between different angular libraries?

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have an angular 10 application with user section that I separated to a different library
in order to make it generic and publish on github.

the user library contains the following modules:
`login-page`,`login-tab`,`profile-page`,`register-tab` and `shared`.

the login tab module needs to get some subscription parameters for the login command.

so I defined this:

```
export type LoginCallback = (username: string, password: string) => Subscribable<LoginDataToken>;
```

now since I separated the `login-page` and `login-tab`, i need to create a different forRoot() for both of them to receive an options class that contain the loginCallback variable.

so I created this:

```
import {LoginCallback} from '@com-tuxin/user/src/lib/shared';

export class LoginTabOptions {

  constructor(public loginCallback: LoginCallback) {
  }

}

@Injectable()
export class LoginTabService {

  public loginCallback: LoginCallback|undefined;

  setLoginCallback(login: ((username: string, password: string) => Subscribable<LoginDataToken>) | undefined): void {
    this.loginCallback = login;
  }

}
```

now if i'm not correct (maybe I am), i should add forRoot() to both `login-page` and `login-tab`,
since the user only requires `login-page`, and i need to transfer the callback to `login-tab`.

so this is my full `login-page.module.ts`:

```
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginPageComponent} from '@com-tuxin/user/src/lib/login-page/login-page.component';
import {FlexModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {RegisterTabModule} from '@com-tuxin/user/src/lib/register-tab';
import {LoginTabModule, LoginTabOptions, LoginTabService} from '@com-tuxin/user/src/lib/login-tab';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [  {path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent} ];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RegisterTabModule,      ### LINE BLOW IS PROBLEMATIC ###
 ###-->      LoginTabModule.forRoot({loginCallback: this.loginTabService.loginCallback}),
 ################   
 FlexModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)

  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPageComponent
  ]
})
export class LoginPageModule {

  constructor(private loginTabService: LoginTabService) {
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  static forRoot(options: LoginTabOptions): ModuleWithProviders<any> {
    return {
      ngModule: LoginPageModule,
      providers: [ {
        provide: LoginTabService,
        useFactory: () => {

          const loginTabService = new LoginTabService();
          loginTabService.setLoginCallback(options.loginCallback);
          return( loginTabService );

        }
      } ]
    };
  }
```

intellij returns an error that `Object is possibly undefined`. I would guess that in that section `this` it not the `this` of the actual class.

so first..
does my method make sense ? the user will load `login-page` and add a `forRoot()` to it and my `login-age` module will load `login-tab` and will provide to it with `forRoot()` the callback and it will use it.

if it's not.. what to do different ?

if it is.. how do I correct it ? the module needs to get the service with `forRoot()` and send it with `forRoot()` to the `login-tab` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach: add `LoginTabModule` to `imports` array and spread LoginTabModule `providers` in `forRoot` section:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoginTabModule,  <============== tell Angular that you're going
                                     to use declarables from this module
    ...

  ],
  ...
})
export class LoginPageModule {
  static forRoot(options: LoginTabOptions): ModuleWithProviders<any> {
    return {
      ngModule: LoginPageModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LoginTabService,
          useFactory: () => {
            ...
          }
        },
        ...LoginTabModule.forRoot(options).providers, <== use providers from LoginTabModule
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: when adding the .providers line I get Type 'Provider[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: and also how in the main module i load LoginPageModule with forroot() and pasting it a function that I have in a service? how do I inject that ?

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-heuurg?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin-page%2Flogin-page.module.ts

Comment: so I added the service my-app.service.ts https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tfjsa3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-app.service.ts

Comment: this service is in the main app, i use it for graphql and i want to send the login function there, so how do I paste this service in the main app to the login-page to the login-tab ?

Comment: the original service has an apollo client injected in it's constructor

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wdwsgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin-tab%2Flogin-tab.module.ts

Comment: thank you so much for your time. didn't know i can just paste the service class. i still don't understand why adding the providers line giving me this error, for some reason stackblitz won't compile the project for me anymore, i'll try to reproduce it and i'll post it here

Comment: thank you.. it works. just a question, i needed to add ! at the end of the .providers so i won't get this error. any ideas why ? i took it from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12707

Comment: Because if you won't add it then TS will think that providers? property is 'undefined' and you can't spread undefined. Another possible solution is to use fallback like ...(LoginTabModule.forRoot(options).providers || [])